# Wordpress Plugin to insert data in db via backend form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress plugin. It's my first one but even so, I read a lot of tutorials I don't know how to do that.
I want to build a very simple plugin:
I want to insert data (some text and a date) with a form in the backend in a DB table.
What I got so far:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_create_plugin_table' );

function myplugin_create_plugin_table(){
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'myplugin';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      text varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}

function myplugin_insert_data($text){
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->insert( 
        'table', 
        array( 
            'text' => $text,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s',
            '%s' 
        ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: this is way too broad for the scope of SO - actually you might be better off asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ but it's still likely to be considered too broad.

Answer (score 0):

change as per your requirement

```
 function createa_tables()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'mytable`
    (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`fname` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`lname` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`phone` VARCHAR( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM;');

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'createa_tables');
```

Comment: The problem is not creating a table but how I build a form in the backend to enter data that gets inserted in the table

Comment: change as per your requirement

Comment: you want add data also